# PHPStorm, Phpunit PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::addFileToBlacklist()

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

When i start the PhpUnit tests (phpunit.phar) from command line everything is  fine.

If i start the tests from PhpStorm it throws this error

```
PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::addFileToBlacklist()
```

I use PhpStorm 9.

Comment: 1) Which "PhpStorm 9" version exactly? 2) PHPUnit version?

Comment: PhpStorm: 9.0.2  PHP: 5.6.14 PHPUnit: 5.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the EAP build you can temporary pin your phpunit/php-code-coverage to `"phpunit/php-code-coverage": "dev-master#b8436b000263f6d72fbad1d36890e247ce84857e"`

*Bug report on GitHub https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/390*

Answer (score 2):

Please try PhpStorm [v9.5 EAP build](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/09/phpstorm-9-5-eap-142-5282/) -- it supports PHPUnit v5 + helper script got rewritten.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27017
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29023

Comment: the eap build is to buggy i get some other problems if i use this